# Remove empty rows at the end of a csv file being saved using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am very new to VBA. I was trying to save a tab from an excel worksheet into a separate csv file using VBA and below is the code I used. However, the code creates a csv file but the file size is significantly large. For example, even if the worksheet has just three rows, the csv file created would be of 21 MB. The reason being, my excel worksheet is filled with formulas for a 1000 rows and 20 columns. Also the number of entries will vary. Therefore after the execution, the csv would have empty rows(output attached as image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76imo.png). I just want to modify the code so that the empty rows(only the entire empty rows across 20 columns) are deleted from the csv. Any help is much appreciated.

****Code:****

```
Sub CREATE_CSV()

  Sheet6.Unprotect Password:="1000"

  Dim MyPath As String
  Dim MyFileName As String

  MyPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  MyFileName = "Titles_Footnotes"

  If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"  
  If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"

  Sheets("Titles_Footnotes").Copy
  ActiveSheet.Range("1:4").EntireRow.Delete    
  ActiveSheet.Range("U:Z").EntireColumn.Delete    

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True            

  With ActiveWorkbook        
    Dim URvalues    
    Dim usedRangeAddress As String     
    usedRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address
    URvalues = ActiveSheet.UsedRange      
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete     
    Range(usedRangeAddress) = URvalues

    .SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV,CreateBackup:=False  
   
    .Close False
   End With

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
   Sheet6.Protect Password:="1000", AllowFiltering:=True

   MsgBox ("CSV Created!")
  End Sub
```

Comment: Try `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With` - basically converting the new sheet to values before saving as csv.

Comment: Thank you for the comment BigBen. Can you please let me know where should I add the *With ActiveSheet.UsedRange* code in the code  I have written? Is it within the *With Activeworkbook -- End with*

Comment: After the `With ActiveWorkbook`. I'd do `With .Worksheets(1).UsedRange`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With`.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately the entire excel hangs and says (Not Responding)!!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with how you tried it (the code attempt), to make sure it was done correctly?

Comment: I did edit my question. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure why Excel would hang. What happens if you do this step manually (i.e. copy/paste values on the new sheet before saving as csv)?

Comment: I was trying to automate it rather than manually doing it. Just another thing, the excel workbook that I am trying to export to CSV has an active control button which says *Create CSV* and the intention is that the user clicks the button and the same workbook gets saved as a CSV. Do you think that  it might be causing a problem?

Comment: My suggestion to do it manually was just to do it manually *once*, to see if the CSV that is saved doesn't have all those extra rows. If it doesn't work manually, then you need an alternative.

Comment: I also did try to do it manually and the output is exactly the same with empty rows in the bottom with the file size being significantly large.

Comment: Do your formulas return a blank string `""`?

Comment: I have 998 rows in total with formulas, only three rows being filled currently by the users. But when I try to export this into a CSV, the first three rows appear correctly,  along with empty rows filled with commas until  the total 998 records!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What do your formulas return in the empty rows?

Comment: Just a background, this workbook with formulas get the data from another workbook. So right now apart from the first three rows, the rest of the rows are blank and do not have any anything in the excel sheet, i.e. from row number 4 to 998 the excel sheet is empty.

Comment: So the formulas return nothing if the data in the other workbook is empty.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Formulas always return *something*. What is that something?

Comment: Okay so let me tell you the formula: =If(Tracker!A8="","",Tracker!A8), where Tracker is another workbook.

Comment: As I guessed, that formula returns a blank string (which is not the same as nothing).

Comment: Okay, I didn't know this. Thank you. So do you think the problem lies in the formula that I have written?

Comment: No. Normally converting to values should eliminate the blank strings. I'm not sure why it's not working in your case.

Comment: Pradeep.. Replace the above `With __ .Value = .Value __ End With` block with `Dim URvalues
    Dim usedRangeAddress As String
    'Get UsedRange Address prior to deleting Range
    usedRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address
    'Store values of cells to array.
    URvalues = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'Delete all cells in the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
    'Restore values to their initial locations
    Range(usedRangeAddress) = URvalues`
 ... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052452/9808063). Upvote it if it solves the problem :)

Comment: Hello Naresh, first of all thank you for your comment. I have updated the question with the code that you have given. I am still getting the same result, that is empty rows with commas. Have I included the block correctly?